# Какая есть альтернатива jquery для работы с backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

BackboneJS для работы с `Backbone.View` требует jquery. Я не пишу на jquery по религиозным соображениям и использую VanillaJS.
Собственно, для того, чтобы сработал поиск по DOM внутри Backbone, нужно подключить целую библу, которую я использовать не буду и которая при этом весит не мало.

Вопрос: есть ли альтернатива jquery для backbone? Может есть библиотека, в которой есть только DOM-манипуляции, чтобы сэкономить на ее размере?
Я в курсе про Zepto, которая очень легковесная, однако она сама по себе медленнее jquery 2 и это наверняка будет сказываться на работе `Backbone.View` как-то.

Какие есть альтернативы jquery для backbone?

Comment: Привет единоверцу) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241831/does-backbone-js-have-a-hard-dependency-on-jquery

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Но я тут нашел отличное решение! -)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Альтернативы: jbone (2.5kb) и sprint (5kb). Оба используют jquery-подобный API. При этом судя по тестам спринт значительно быстрее всех jquery-подобных библиотек.

---

Пруфы:

[Сравнение jbone](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-queryselectorall/25)

[Сравнение sprint](http://jsperf.com/zepto-vs-jquery-2013/103)

Однако с бэкбоном нужно использовать jbone. Она отрабатывает корректно, в отличие от sprint с помощью которого не определяется View.el